# Automating Snapshots on Elasticsearch cluster running on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have an Elasticsearch cluster running on EC2 instances and I want to automate snapshots to backup daily.

I've read through the Snapshot and Restore guide and I have the PUT command that'll make a snapshot. From my research I've seen a few ways to automate the backups. One suggestion I found was to use AWS managed Elasticsearch. Unfortunately switching to managed Elasticsearch will not work due to other constraints we have.

The first approach I tried was to set up a cron job on one of the nodes that would make the appropriate REST call. However I realized that if the node running the command were to go down, then the backups wouldn't run.

The next approach I though to use was AWS Datapipeline. The issue is that there doesn't seem to be a way to send REST calls from Datapipeline - I could run an EC2 shell command, but then I'd run into the same problem as before.

The other approach I've thought of is using a CloudWatch event to schedule a lambda function that'll make the REST call. It seems like that might work best, but it also seems overly complicated for automating backups.

Is there a way to automate backups from within Elasticsearch? And if not is there a simpler way of doing this with AWS services?

Comment: Elastic has a tool for that, it's called [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/about.html), you can use it to automate [snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/snapshot.html) and schedule with crontab.

Comment: You can also use "AWS Backup" service and specify how often do you want EBS snapshots created and retention period.

Comment: @leandrojmp Would I need to spin up a separate EC2 instance to run the cron job? What benefit does curator provide for this use case over curl and crontab?

Comment: @Andrysha Does AWS Backup makes full disk backup? If so then the EBS snapshot wouldn't be able to utilize the structure of the Elasticsearch cluster and it would end up duplicating any data that existed on multiple nodes of the cluster.

Comment: @automatoney Yes, it's a full disk backup. You are right about duplicating data if taking snapshot of every single EC2 instance. Depending on how big your infrastructure is and how are your shards distributed it might not be efficient. If more control desired then either API call or curator is a better option. As far as scheduling I would recommend CloudWatch event + lambda.

Comment: @automatoney with curator you use yml config files to specify what and how you want to make your snapshots, you don't need to care about the REST request, it's simplier. it's a simple python tool that can be installed in one of your nodes.

Comment: @automatoney Also, the only [reliable way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/modules-snapshots.html) to make a backup/snapshot of your elasticsearch data is through the snapshot/restore API, disk backups cannot guarantee integrity of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Elasticsearch cluster running on versions before 7.3, using a CloudWatch event to schedule a lambda function that'll make the REST call to do a snapshot is a resilient way to schedule backups as it avoids dependency on a single node running a cron job while also performing a reliable Elasticsearch backup (see the comments on the question for details).

A new feature in Elasticsearch 7.4 is snapshot lifecycle management which allows you to automatically back up Elasticsearch indices using the snapshots every day at a particular time.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-snapshot-lifecycle-management.html